# Standalone tikz graphic with invisible Y-axis label

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, xetex, standalone, matlab2tikz

I want to compile a standalone tikz graphic using XelaTeX and include it in a larger document. The MWE shows the effect. When I do, the Y-axis labels disappear. The X-axis label remains. If I add a `ylabel shift` (marked "this line" in picture code), the output image changes as though a label had moved, but it still can't be seen.

If I view the picture with TikzEdt it has a label.

[image: yLabelShift on] [image: yLabelShift on]

The main:

```
%magic comment
% !TeX program = txs:///xelatex | txs:///view-pdf
\documentclass{article} %[smallcondensed]{svjour3}
\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}
\newcommand{\fileNameOfTIKZ}{filename}
\newlength\figureheight %for variable size tikz
\newlength\figurewidth 
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[hptb!]
    \renewcommand{\fileNameOfTIKZ}{pic}
    \setlength\figureheight{100pt} 
    \setlength\figurewidth{\textwidth}
    \includestandalone[width=\textwidth]{\fileNameOfTIKZ}
    \caption{A graph without a y-label.}
    \label{img}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Sample Picture:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}   
\begin{document}    
\setlength\figureheight{100pt}
\setlength\figurewidth{\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{axis}[%
    width=\figurewidth,
    height=0.696\figureheight,
    at={(0\figurewidth,0\figureheight)},
    scale only axis,
    unbounded coords=jump,
    xmin=0,
    xmax=800,
    xtick={\empty},
    xlabel={Time},
    ymin=-5,
    ymax=2.2797697532885,
    ytick={\empty},
    ylabel={Performance},
%this line%ylabel shift = -10 pt,
    title style={font=\bfseries},
    legend style={at={(0.97,0.03)},anchor=south east,legend cell    align=left,align=left,draw=white!15!black}]
\addplot [color=red,dashdotted,line width=1.0pt]
    table[row sep=crcr]{%
    1   -inf\\
    2   -0.366512920581664\\
    3   0.0940478276166989\\
    };
    \addlegendentry{Line 1};

\addplot [color=black!30!green,solid,line width=1.0pt]
      table[row sep=crcr]{%
    1   -5\\
    2   -4.30685281944005\\
    3   -3.90138771133189\\
    };
    \addlegendentry{Line 2};    
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is pdfLaTeX an option? Or LuaLaTeX?

Comment: Originally I switched to xeTex before using standalone because of memory issues, but these are now resolved.  pdfLaTex renders Y-labels as expected.

Comment: It is just that the problem seems to be engine-specific. I can reproduce with XeLaTeX, but not pdfLaTeX or LuaLaTeX - those seem to work fine.

Comment: agreed, for now I'm happy to work around it with other compilers.  Interesting though, doesn't seem a likely bug.